# IntelliJ paste error in windows 7

Tags: intellij-idea, copy-paste, windows-7-x64, intellij-14

Not sure when this started happening, but intelliJ pasted wont work if copying from IE, chrome or firefox. In the idea.log I see the following error.  Anyone have any idea why?

> 2015-09-23 13:52:06,446 [421686658]  ERROR -
>   llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Comparison method violates its
>   general contract!  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison
>   method violates its general contract!     at
>   java.util.TimSort.mergeHi(TimSort.java:895)   at
>   java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:512)   at
>   java.util.TimSort.mergeCollapse(TimSort.java:437)     at
>   java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:241)  at
>   java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1438)   at
>   sun.awt.datatransfer.DataTransferer.setToSortedDataFlavorArray(DataTransferer.java:2410)
>     at
>   sun.awt.datatransfer.ClipboardTransferable.(ClipboardTransferable.java:101)
>     at
>   sun.awt.datatransfer.SunClipboard.getContents(SunClipboard.java:144)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ide.ClipboardSynchronizer$ClipboardHandler.getContents(ClipboardSynchronizer.java:147)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ide.ClipboardSynchronizer.getContents(ClipboardSynchronizer.java:110)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ide.CopyPasteManagerEx.getContents(CopyPasteManagerEx.java:238)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.editor.EditorModificationUtil.getContentsToPasteToEditor(EditorModificationUtil.java:204)
>     at
>   com.intellij.codeInsight.editorActions.PasteHandler.execute(PasteHandler.java:80)
>     at
>   com.intellij.codeInsight.editorActions.PasteHandler.doExecute(PasteHandler.java:75)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.editor.actionSystem.EditorActionHandler$4.perform(EditorActionHandler.java:217)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.editor.actionSystem.EditorActionHandler.doIfEnabled(EditorActionHandler.java:109)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.editor.actionSystem.EditorActionHandler.execute(EditorActionHandler.java:214)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.editor.actionSystem.EditorAction$1.run(EditorAction.java:98)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:124)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.editor.actionSystem.EditorAction.actionPerformed(EditorAction.java:109)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.editor.actionSystem.EditorAction.actionPerformed(EditorAction.java:83)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher$3.performAction(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:586)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.processAction(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:637)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.inInitState(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:476)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.dispatchKeyEvent(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:212)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:538)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:382)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
>   2015-09-23 13:52:06,446 [421686658]  ERROR -
>   llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.2  Build
>
> ## IC-141.713.2  2015-09-23 13:52:06,446 [421686658]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 1.8.0_40  2015-09-23
>
> 13:52:06,446 [421686658]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - VM:
>   Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM  2015-09-23 13:52:06,446 [421686658]  ERROR
>   - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Vendor: Oracle Corporation  2015-09-23 13:52:06,446 [421686658]  ERROR -
>   llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Windows 7  2015-09-23
>   13:52:06,447 [421686659]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager -
>   Last Action: EditorPaste

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to start intellij in **administrator** mode?

Comment: since I start intellj with administrator mode, I don't face this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [JDK issue](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=7173464). It has been reported multiple times. I'm not quite sure in which version it is actually fixed, but from what I understand, you (or Intellij) cannot do anything about it. It still happens in our application with a recent Java 8 version.